# parallel/asynchrone load heavy ui wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mvvm, task-parallel-library

I have some issue loading my app, it takes too much time. So i want to optimize the code using .net 4.5. I already replace my code with async/await pattern for WCF calls, I/O operations and some calculations. I even used compression with GZip to reduce the loading time. It works very well, i saved few seconds.

After a few test i realize that the main loading time is due to the UI initialization (>20s).

My app is based on the MVVM Light Framework. One `MainWindow` bound on `MainViewModel`. The `MainViewModel` has a `List<DataViewModel> DataViewModelList` property. Each `DataViewModel` has a `List<ViewModelBase> ViewModelBaseList` property. Those `ViewModelBase` can be `ServiceUnitViewModel` typed bound to `ServiceUnitView`, `SearchViewModel` typed bound to `SearchView` etc...

The `MainWindow` is composed by a `TabControl` with `ItemsSource={Binding DataViewModelList}`. So its `TabItem` datacontext is a `DataViewModel`. Each `TabItem` is a `TabControl` with `ItemsSource={Binding ViewModelBaseList}`. Each `TabItem` is a `UserControl` whose datacontext is either a `ServiceUnitViewModel` or a `SearchViewModel`... One view (`ServiceUnitView`, `SearchView`...) at a time is displayed following the selection => `DataViewModel x + ViewModelBase y`

```
//MainViewModel.cs
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private List<DataViewModel> _dataViewModelList;
    public List<DataViewModel> DataViewModelList
    {
        get { return _dataViewModelList; }
        set
        {
            if (_dataViewModelList == value)
                return;

            _dataViewModelList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("DataViewModelList");
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        DataViewModelList = new List<DataViewModel>();
    }
}

//DataViewModel.cs
public class DataViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> _viewModelBaseList;
    public ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> ViewModelBaseList
    {
        get { return _viewModelBaseList; }
        set
        {
            if (_viewModelBaseList == value)
                return;

            _viewModelBaseList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ViewModelBaseList");
        }
    }

    public DataViewModel(MainViewModel mainViewModel)
    {
        MainViewModel = mainViewModel;
        ViewModelBaseList = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>();
    }
}

//ServiceUnitViewModel.cs
public class ServiceUnitViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public DataViewModel DataViewModel { get; set; }
    public ServiceUnitView View { get; set; }

    public ServiceUnitViewModel(DataViewModel dataViewModel)
    {
        DataViewModel = dataViewModel;
        View = new ServiceUnitView(this);
    }
}

//SearchViewModel.cs
public class SearchViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public DataViewModel DataViewModel { get; set; }
    public SearchView View { get; set; }

    public SearchViewModel(DataViewModel dataViewModel)
    {
        DataViewModel = dataViewModel;
        View = new SearchView(this);
    }
}

//MainWindow.cs
<TabControlEx x:Name="TabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding DataViewModelList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDataViewModel}">
<TabControlEx.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding DataViewModelIsSelected}"/>
    </Style>
</TabControlEx.Resources>
<TabControlEx.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TabControlEx ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModelBaseList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedViewModelBase}">
            <TabControlEx.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <UserControl Content="{Binding View}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControlEx.ContentTemplate>
            <TabControlEx.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding ViewModelBaseIsSelected}"/>
                </Style>
            </TabControlEx.Resources>
        </TabControlEx>
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControlEx.ContentTemplate>
```

[Code diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYQk4.png)

Each View (UserControl) are relatively heavy. For example the ServiceUnitView is composed by a lot of BedRoom (UserControl) and other stuff, each BedRoom is composed by some Bed (UserControl) and other stuff, each Bed is composed by some Patient (UserControl)...

Each logged user has some specific service (DataViewModelList) and some specific View on each service (ViewModelBaseList). The loading time can be >20s in some cases.

I tried to load each DataViewModel in parallel but i didn't succeed.

```
foreach(Service service in User.Services)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //crash after a while when trying to update some UI Control (refresh method)(DependencySource must be on same Thread that DependencyObject)
        DataViewModel dataViewModel = new DataViewModel(MainViewModel);
        MainViewModel.DataViewModelList.Add(dataViewModel);

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            foreach(string view in service.views)
            {
                ViewModelBase vmb;
                if (view == "ServiceUnitView")
                    //crash because i can't do View = new ServiceUnitView(this) in ServiceUnitViewModel because it's not the UI thread
                    vmb = new ServiceUnitViewModel(dataViewModel);
                else if (view == "SearchView")
                    vmb = new SearchViewModel(dataViewModel);
                else
                    continue;

                dataViewModel.ViewModelBaseList.Add(vmb); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Similar issues with `Parallel.ForEach`

Is there a way to load heavy nested UserControl without freezing the ui. Reduce time with parallel load ? I tried Dispatcher.Invoke stuff to warn the UI thread to update the ui but my main issue IS to create views so it doesn't change anything (same loading time). The ui load is still sequential in this way, no ?
There is a lot of tutorial, but each time it's too simple examples (Console.Writeline, async/paralel on I/O, WCF, DataBase..., no ui update), or ui updates are made in synchrone (equivalent to completed backgroundworker).

i read a lot of publications from [Stephen Cleary](http://blog.stephencleary.com/) (very good guy)
and other post since 8 days, i can't do it by myself and i need your help. If you need some clarification let me know.

Comment: We are sorting out similar problem by using 2 controls in same grid - one is busy indicator (rounding circle) second is real control. When background tasks are finished we are simply switching visibility of controls - hiding busy indicator and showing real control.

Comment: Do you have any idea where the bottleneck is? Do you have any CPU intensive/IO operations somewhere during the UI buildup? 20 seconds is quite a lot for just building up the UI.

Comment: @smartobelix the purpose was to accelerate the treatment. What i did at first was to display :     <pre><br/> Loading Service 1 - Loading BedView - Loading SearchView <br/> Loading Service 2 - Loading BedView - Loading SearchView</pre>

Comment: Ok, then you should create view models in parallel tasks, but at the end assign them to properties using Dispatcher.Invoke or better BeginInvoke.

Comment: @sondergard client machine : Pentium DualCore 3.20GHz 4go. About 10 to 20% for the first 20s (initialization) then 40% for the rendering i guess the last 5s